# Can you pass a pointer to javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to save function from local scope to a global variable to be able to access it from another local scope. Is it possible somehow?

```
var someFunc1 = function(){ return 1;}
var someFunc2 = function(){ return 2;}

globalFunc = someFunc1; // now globalFunc points to someFunc1

var localFunc = globalFunc; // now localFunc points to globalFunc

globalFunc = someFunc2;
```

now `localFunc` points to `globalFunc ==> someFunc2`, but I want `localFunc==someFunc1`. If I could save a pointer into `globalFunc` *(like in c++ I think)*, and then copy it to `localFunc`, I would handle that.

Comment: Why don't you follow js in object oriented way to handle such situation.

Comment: But `localFunc` is pointing to `someFunc1`, https://jsfiddle.net/h2uLe7du/

Comment: I agree with you Babu. Are you finding a more complex way to achieve your aim?